# Setting Thread Affinities in Docker Containers

Tags: multithreading, docker

I have an application which has one thread that runs with 100% CPU usage. This thread reads and processes data from RAM that is populated by a group of 10 threads that wait on system IO to retrieve data.

In my Linux environment I will isolate one CPU and then assign the core, spinning, thread to that core cpu. All other reader threads will be scheduled by the OS on all of the schedulable CPU's.

If I need to run additional instances of my application we would isolate another CPU and put the second instance's core reader thread onto that isolated CPU.  Again, the reading threads are IO bound and will happily go along with the system scheduler.

This is simple enough to set up manually with isolation set up as needed and the each instance of the application having a reserved core for it's critical thread.

How can this transition to docker? I'd like to run Docker containers so that I can run many instances across various hosts for Docker (including AWS Batch). But then in a Docker scenario, how can we have every instance allocate CPU's without stepping on each-other's cores?  When we call `pthread_setaffinity_np()` to set the core how can we know which thread to use in a dynamically allocated container environment?

Comment: Does the CPU pinning gain you anything in practice?  If you're looking at cloud environments, you may not have that much control over which core or which host you're actually using.

Comment: If I can truly isolate a core in the cloud environment it is defintely helpful.   It doesn't matter which core, from my app's perspective it would be OK to let the app select core 1 but to have Docker map core 1 to any unique core.

Comment: Docker can do this with the `--cpuset` option. https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/